# HTML <div> to pdf using jsPDF

Tags: html, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to download a div into PDF using jsPDF with this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Page to print</h3>
        </div>
        <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
     </body>

  </html>  
  <script>      
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#cmd').click(function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addHTML($('#content')[0], 15, 15, {
        'background': '#FFFFFF',
        }, function() {
           doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        });
     });
  });
  </script>
```

When i click on the button nothing is happening, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add it in the head

```
<script src="https://javascriptbase64.googlecode.com/files/base64.js"></script>
  <script src="https://sprintf.googlecode.com/files/sprintf-0.7-beta1.js"></script>
```

Comment: See this example maybe can help you. https://www.webhosting.uk.com/forums/web-designing-development/6718-jspdf-generating-your-pdf-web-page-documents-using-javascript.html